# SSO user activating the page..triggers the workflow with workflow launcher but shows initiator as admin..Any suggestions why initiator as admin?

Tags: aem

Team,

I have a workflow with only one process step, which is processMyCustomStep, mapped to an OSGI service.

I have a sso user belonging to the custom AEM group. He has full access to /etc, /content and /libs.

I have logged in as SSO user, when activating the page, it kicks off the workflow with the workflow launcher cq:page modified event. But shows the initiator as "admin".

workflow instance history

Status      Title   Initiator   Start Time  End Time    Action  Comment
Completed   Start   admin   12-06-2016 2:58:27  12-06-2016 2:58:27  WorkflowCompleted
Completed   processMyCustomStep admin   12-06-2016 2:58:27  12-06-2016 2:58:27  WorkflowCompleted

Couple of questions I have:

1. Not sure what is this Title Start probably workflow launcher starting the workflow, but it shows the initiator as admin.
2. At the same time, my workflow process step also shows the initiator as admin.
3. Due to initiator of workflow as admin, when I logged in as sso user, I am not seeing the instances for this workflow and also in archive for the sso user. Only when logged in as admin, I see the workflow instances and in archive once workflow is completed.

Instead of activating a page and workflow launcher triggering the workflow, I manually started the workflow process by providing the payload of the page and then it shows correctly, the workflow process started with initiator as sso user.

workflow instance history

Status      Title   Initiator   Start Time  End Time    Action  Comment
Completed   Start   SSOUser1    12-06-2016 2:56:24  12-06-2016 2:58:27  WorkflowCompleted
Completed   processMyCustomStep admin   12-06-2016 2:56:24  12-06-2016 2:58:27  WorkflowCompleted
 This time since the initiator is SSOUser1, I see the workflow instances populated when logged in as sso user(SSOUser1). I also see the workflow instance in the archive once completed.

**Even though I am activating the page with sso user in the first case, not sure why it shows the initiator of the workflow as admin instead of sso user. Any suggestions for the sso user to be able to see the workflow instances after activating the page when logged in as sso user. Its triggering the workflow but with initiator as admin instead of sso user. Any inputs will be highly appreciated.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The initiator is always `admin` or `workflow-service` in newer AEM versions that use Sling service accounts. The user requests the start of the workflow and the admin or service account runs the process. If you want to find the user who kicked off the workflow you can look in the meta data with `item.getWorkflowData().getMetaDataMap().get("userId", String.class)`. Notice that data matches the resources created in the JCR at a path similar to `/etc/workflow/instances/server0/2016-06-13/update_asset_2/data/metaData`. Furthermore, you can get the participant of individual workflow process steps by getting the `HistoryItem` and then the `userId`.

```
@Component
@Service
@Properties({
    @Property(name = Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION, value = "Workflow step description"),
    @Property(name = Constants.SERVICE_VENDOR, value = "Company Name"),
    @Property(name = "process.label", value = "Process Label will show in the workflow dropdown") })
public class MyCustomStep implements WorkflowProcess {

    public void execute(WorkItem item, WorkflowSession wfsession, MetaDataMap args) throws WorkflowException {

        /* Always admin or service-workflow */
        final String initiator = item.getWorkflow().getInitiator();

        /* Get actual user who initiated workflow */
        final String initiator = item.getWorkflowData().getMetaDataMap().get("userId", String.class);

        /* Get workflow history */
        final List<HistoryItem> histories = wfsession.getHistory(item.getWorkflow());

        /* Get last item in workflow history */
        final HistoryItem lastItem = histories.get(histories.size() - 1);

        /* Get the user that participated in the last item */
        final String lastUser = lastItem.getUserId();
    }
}
```

The workflow `title` is created by the user that initiates the workflow. See the following screenshot of the workflow initiation dialog from the Classic UI's Site Admin: [image: Workflow initiation]